# Trying to combine navigators causes app to crash

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble trying to combine two navigators together in my app. I want to have a `StackNavigator` that is the main navigator for the entirety of the app, but I also want a `MaterialTopTabNavigator` for one of the screens. The problem that I am encountering is that whenever I try to add the `MaterialTopTabNavigator`, the app will always crash and get the red screen. I tried to add the navigator in multiple ways. I first tried to add it in a different component and this called an `Undefined on the object` error and then I added the navigator in my `App.js` file where the main `StackNavigator` is also located. If I delete the `MaterialTopTabNavigator` then the `StackNavigator` works perfectly fine.

This where the navigators are in my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import SearchScreen from "./src/screens/SearchScreen";
import Loading from "./src/components/Loading";
import PickerList from "./src/components/PickerList";
import Summary from "./src/components/Summary";
import Timeline from "./src/components/Timeline";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
// import ResultsScreen from "./src/screens/ResultsScreen";
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <AppStackContainer />;
  }
}

const ResultsNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Summary: Summary,
    Timeline: Timeline
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "top",
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      inactiveTintColor: "#F8F8F8",
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#633689"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        textAlign: "center"
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "#87B56A",
        borderBottomWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
);

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: SearchScreen,
    Picker: PickerList,
    Results: ResultsNavigator
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "orange"
      }
    }
  }
);



const AppStackContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 600,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});
```

The expected output should be a working stack navigator with one screen containing a tab navigator, but the output is a red screen error containing an error about something being undefined.

These are the errors in the console

```
ExceptionsManager.js:86 Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
ExceptionsManager.js:94 Unable to find module for EventDispatcher
ExceptionsManager.js:86 Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
Unhandled JS Exception: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: It kind of changes but the one that my console is displaying right now is

Comment: `Cannot read property 'create' of undefined`

Comment: and `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)` and this also are repeated with but with `Unhandled JS exceptions` in front of them

Comment: I have added the errors in an edit for better readablitiy

Comment: Is the navigation code APP.js?

Comment: Yes, They are located in my `App.js` file.

Comment: It works if you are using only the stackNavigator?

Comment: Yeah, if you get rid of all the code pertaining to `ResultsNavigator` from the `App.js` file, then the code works and functions as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `App.js` code as below. I first deleted the `stylesheet` that made the error, and I declared that I would not create an `app class`, but that I would bring the basic item right away.

Please enter a command in the command before attempting this code.

1. run command `killall -9 node`
2. run command `npm start --reset-cache`
3. run command `react-native run-ios` OR `react-native run-android`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, Text, View } from "react-native";
import SearchScreen from "./src/screens/SearchScreen";
import Loading from "./src/components/Loading";
import PickerList from "./src/components/PickerList";
import Summary from "./src/components/Summary";
import Timeline from "./src/components/Timeline";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator
} from "react-navigation";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});


const ResultsNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
     summary: {
      screen: Summary
    },
    timeline: {
      screen: Timeline
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "top",
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      inactiveTintColor: "#F8F8F8",
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#633689"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        textAlign: "center"
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: "#87B56A",
        borderBottomWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
);

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: SearchScreen
    },
    PickList: {
      screen: PickerList
    },
    Results: {
      screen: ResultsNavigator
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "orange"
      }
    }
  }
);



const AppStackContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);

export default AppStackContainer;
```

Comment: I tried this and the same errors had popped up as before.

Comment: I made some changes to the code. Would you like to try again?